# Can't create/write to file '/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log'

Tags: mariadb, logging

I'm troubleshooting a MySQL no-start on CentOS 7 VM. It is a bit unusual to see this since we have not made any configuration changes. The manual start command was taken from systemd logging. The error is the age old:

```
# /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --basedir=/usr
181221 17:42:49 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log'.
181221 17:42:49 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
/usr/bin/mysqld_safe_helper: Can't create/write to file '/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log' (Errcode: 13)
```

According to [Red Hat Bugzilla – Bug 1061045](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1061045), `mysql:mysql` needs the appropriate permissions, which we seem to have:

```
[root@ftpit w]# ls -Al /var/log
total 52764
...
drwxrwx---  2 mysql mysql      4096 Aug 16 11:05 mariadb
```

And:

```
[root@ftpit w]# ls -Al /var/log/mariadb/
total 99852
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 102138776 Dec 21 17:16 mariadb.log
```

And:

```
[root@ftpit w]# grep mysql /etc/passwd
mysql:x:27:27:MariaDB Server:/var/lib/mysql:/sbin/nologin
```

I also tried `g-w` as shown in the bug report.

Where should I look next for this error? Or how do I fix it?

Comment: Does the file exist? I see a similar issue in MariaDB reports but the suggestion was to manually create the file (with mysql as owner): https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-11841

Comment: @yper-crazyhat-cubeᵀᴹ - Yes, the file exists. Do you know if the file size of 102138776 is relevant? (`df -h` shows plenty of space).

Comment: The issue might be related to SELinux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is SELinux running in enforcing mode? Run `sestatus` to find out. If so, it should be logging to the `/var/log/audit/` directory. You can do `grep mysql /var/log/audit/*` to see if there are any problems related to "mysql" i.e. MariaDB.

Also, the correct privileges and SELinux context for the log directory and files are:

```
# ls -ldZ /var/log/mariadb/ drwxr-x---. mysql mysql 
system_u:object_r:mysqld_log_t:s0 /var/log/mariadb/
# ls -ldZ /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log
-rw-r-----. mysql mysql system_u:object_r:mysqld_log_t:s0 /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log
```

For instructions on how to set the right SELinux context, refer to the documentation: [What to Do if MariaDB Doesn't Start - SELinux and MariaDB Path Changes](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/what-to-do-if-mariadb-doesnt-start/#selinux-and-mariadb-path-changes).

Comment: Whoops, scratch that last comment. `sestatus` returned `SELinux status: disabled`. Gotta love CentOS 7 out of the box. Antique software and no SELinux. (I think Fedora does a better job than Red Hat).

Comment: OK, so a reboot fixed it even though no software or updates had been installed. Gotta love CentOS 7... Thanks for the help.